# Can I use run_time in Scheduled Query with New Big Query UI?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery scheduled query in BigQuery Classic UI (old UI).
In the old UI, I was able to use as a Destination table: `{run_time-15h|"%Y%m%d"}`.

I would like to use `{run_time}` as a Destination table in the New BigQuery UI.

However, If I set `{run_time|"%Y%m%d"}` as Destination Table, the Schedule button disables.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE 
    _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE(
        "%Y%m%d",
        DATE_SUB(
             DATE(@run_time,"Asia/Tokyo"),
             INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

I'm using as destination table: `page_{run_time-15h|"%Y%m%d"}` and write preference: `WRITE_TRUNCATE`

How do I use `{run_time}` as Destination table in New BigQuery UI?

Comment: Hi Yskfj, I replicated your issue, scheduled the query that you pointed and specified as name `page_{run_time-15h|"%Y%m%d"}`. It worked, created the table and the results are the expected. Could you please detail more, the steps that you are taking, so we can reproduce your scenario. Thanks

Comment: now, it works.. i couldnt update ScheduledQuery asked time(5days ago) . i can update ScheduledQuery now. i supporse my browser was not good or something. thank you commented my question.